# How to edit a message and reset cooldown(slash command discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I've done various searches both in the documentation and in stackoverflow and I haven't found the answer that solves my problem.
I started programming discord bots again after abandoning it about 2 years and unfortunately with the slash command I'm just having so many problems. I've been trying to create a clear command for 3 days and luckily it works... but I can't edit the message on my cooldown so that it continues to lower the seconds for 10 seconds before it deletes the message. I searched the documentation (precisely [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction%20author#interaction)) and found various answers... too bad no one actually helped me and always gave me this error

```
  File "***", line 116, in clear_error
    await ctx.message.edit(embed=embed)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'
```

I then decided to use [him](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=interaction%20author#discord.InteractionResponse.edit_message) and it gave me this error

```
discord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before
```

I'm sure I should do something to make it edit the message always using `interaction.response` but I'm out of ideas...

code:

```py
@app_commands.checks.cooldown(1, 600, key=lambda i: (i.user.id))
@tree.command(name = "clear", description = "Cancella gli ultimi messaggi inviati ", guild=discord.Object(id=guild_id))
async def clear(ctx, limit: int):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    if limit == 0:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Non puoi cancellare 0 messaggi!',
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0x03c03c
    )
    if limit == 1:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Ho cancellato ufficialmente un messaggio!',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    else:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'Ho cancellato ufficialmente {limit} messaggi!',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit)
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color=0xFFD000
    )
    if limit == 1:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato un messaggio',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    else:
        embed.set_author(
            name=f'{ctx.user.name} ha cancellato {limit} messaggi',
            icon_url=f'{ctx.user.avatar}'
        )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Messaggi cancellati da:',
        value=f'{ctx.user.name}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Quantità:',
        value=f'{limit}',
        inline=True
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Canale dove è stato eseguito il comando:',
        value=f'{ctx.channel.mention}',
        inline=True
    )
    await logs_moderazione.send(embed=embed)
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    i = 0
    embed=discord.Embed(
        color=0xa61022
    )
    if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        cd = round(error.retry_after)
        time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=cd))
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description=f"**Riprova tra `{time}`**",
            color=0xa61022
        )
        embed.set_author(
            name=f"Sei in cooldown!",
            icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
        )
        await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed, delete_after=10.0)
        for i in range(8):
            if isinstance(error, app_commands.CommandOnCooldown):
                cd = round(error.retry_after)
                time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=cd))
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    description=f"**Riprova tra `{time}`**",
                    color=0xa61022
                )
                embed.set_author(
                    name=f"Sei in cooldown!",
                    icon_url=ctx.user.avatar
                )
                await ctx.response.edit_message(embed=embed)
```

Libraries I use: `discord.py` and `datetine`
global variable: `logs_moderazione` (is a channel)

the error comes from the last line but it's better to forward all the code. I would also like to understand how to reset the cooldown since I can't anymore.

EDIT: the `ctx` variable is actually `interaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `edit` method is missing, declare the `edit` method:

```
async def edit(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('testing')
    await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
    await message.edit(content='v2')
```

Comment: Or is it `ctx.Message.edit`?

Comment: This works for old style commands.. sadly it doesn't work for slash commands